# wp7 Bing map displays in design view but is just black on emulator and phone-used to work perfectly

Tags: windows-phone-7, dictionary, bing-maps

[image: how map appears on emulator]

as you can see the pin "myTent" is loaded onto the map but it is not displayed.
I took a break from this project for a few weeks but changed nothing relative to the map. Saw somewhere that they replaced the token system with keys but I already have a key so shouldn't affect me?? Do keys expire?I don't think they do.
map is set up normally:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,171,12,12" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Button Content="MyTent" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="63,507,0,0" Name="myTentButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="myTentButton_Click" />
        <Button Content="Find Me" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="209,507,0,0" Name="findMeButton" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="160" Click="findMeButton_Click" />
        <my:Map Height="523" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="map1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="444" CredentialsProvider="------------myKEY--------------" />
    </Grid>
```

Any thoughts on why this is happening now when it worked before?? or other tags which may attract right attention, not sure where the fault is as there is no errors
many thanks, 
MH

Comment: The Bing map keys can expire if you are using a trial key. They last about 9 months I think. You should have received an email from Microsoft before it expires.

Comment: I had the same problem where I was animating the page projection (as a transition animation) in `OnNavigatedTo`. I can't say why, but the map simply would not load any tiles once this animation had been run.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the Map application itself is working ok, it's just that it hasn't displayed the map tiles that should be present in the background. If this is the case, here's a couple of possible suggestions to check, which are not clear from the code snippet you've provided:

- Make sure you're specifying a valid map style (Aerial, Road, Birdseye etc.)?
- Make sure that the location on which the map is centred has imagery available for the zoom level at which the map is being displayed. (i.e. some high-resolution imagery at zoom level 19 is not available at all locations)
- Make sure that your phone has a valid internet connection over which it can connect to the Bing Maps servers in order to retrieve the necessary tiles.

Comment: Got it sorted was something to do with `using`'s I had added for another part of the project, they were interfering for some reason, thanks for the reply